# Error in function text.default() in mraplot

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply a function from the `corto` package to generate a plot, but when I apply the specific code that this R package recommends I always get this error:

```r
png("mra_datamatneg.png",w=2500,h=3000,res=300) 
mraplot(mra_datamatneg,mrs=5)
```

> Error in text.default(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, title, cex = cex, col = "black", : X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s---%d-------*, face 1 at size 16 could not be loaded**

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and R-4.0.3

But I don't know how I can solve it to be able to finally generate the plot. All the R packages of which it may have dependencies or import I already have them installed. Can someone help me, please?.

---

You can see in  the plot to be generated with `mraplot`[image] function.

Comment: Hi, can you create a small reproducible example please to help debug whether if it is a problem with the package code or something local to your pc. (the package authors do not include any examples in `mra` & `mraplot` unfortunately which could be used)

Comment: The following examples shows the 5 most differentially active regulons in Neuroblastoma MYCN Amplification.
Unsurprisingly, the MYCN network is the most affected:
# Alternatively, results can be plotted indicating a number of mrs shows the top deregulated (up or down
png("plots/mra_mycnamp.png",w=2500,h=3000,res=300)
mraplot(mra_mycnamp,mrs=5)
dev.off()
# pdf
#
2

Comment: The above text belongs to a pdf (Master regulator analysis using the corto package-Vignette 1) about this corto package and it is the only example that I have until now relating to the code and error in output  I submit using this code.

Comment: I have just apply for to add or upload a image about the plot to be generated with the mraplot function

Comment: Hi Juan; can you try to create a small [`reproducible example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)  please? I remember at the time of your last comment I had to search for the relevant vignette file -- if you could edit your question to add www paths to where users can find them. Also, the vignette example was taking ages on my (very old and underpowered) laptop so in the end i had to stop it before getting to the plotting stage -- ... cont

Comment: ... can you see if you can create steps to reduce the run-time (i.e. reduce the size of the data or no. of replications etc) and add these to your question. If you can create a small reproducible example, it makes it a lot easier for others to run the code and so hopefully you get an answer. (ps it may also be worth adding your system details)

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this function, thanks for using it!

Your problem seems to be concerning the availability of the font in Linux. Check first of all if printing the image works as a PDF! It seems the problem resides in the rendering of the image in the PNG file.

Best,

Federico